# LEFT JOIN with RIGHT condition

Tags: sql, join, many-to-many, ansi-sql

Let say, I have two tables:

- **Student_Class**: `Student_ID`, `Class_ID`
- **Class**: `Class_ID`, `Attribute_ID`, and other fields

[*Sample data at the bottom*]

Requirements:

1. For given students list corresponding values for their classes with a given attribute.
2. If a student does not take classes with this particular attribute - list NULLs instead.
3. If a row with NULLs is warranted - produce only one such row per student

---

Without conditions #2 and #3 it's a simple `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT sc.student_id, c.*
FROM Student_class sc
JOIN Class c ON sc.class_id=c.class_id
WHERE c.attribute_id = ... AND sc.student_id IN (...)
```

---

Without just #3 it's an `OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT sc.student_id, c.*
FROM Student_class sc
LEFT JOIN Class c ON sc.class_id=c.class_id AND c.attribute_id = ...
WHERE sc.student_id IN (...)
```

---

With all three requirements - I'm struggling.

```
SELECT DISTINCT sc.student_id, c.*
FROM Student_class sc
LEFT JOIN Class c ON sc.class_id=c.class_id AND c.attribute_id = ...
WHERE sc.student_id IN (...)
```

The above produces *NULL row* regardless of whether the class with the attribute is found or not.

---

I was thinking of dynamically creating the `NULL row` for every student on the list and `UNION` it with `INNER JOIN` result.

```
SELECT student_id, NULL, NULL, ... , ... 

UNION 

SELECT sc.student_id, c.*
FROM Student_class sc
JOIN Class c ON sc.class_id=c.class_id
WHERE c.attribute_id = ... AND sc.student_id IN (...)
```

The above requires the right number of NULLs in the first query and, therefore, will not withstand altering of the table.

---

Am I missing something obvious here?

---

Sample data:

Student_Class:

```
Student_ID   Class_ID

0001         0050
0001         0150
0002         0050
0002         0100
0002         0155
0002         1200
0002         1155
0003         1155
0004         0050
0004         0155
```

Class:

```
Class_ID   Attribute_ID  Value1 Value2 Value3

0050       A1            1      2      3
0100       A2            4      5      6
0150       A3            7      8      9
0155       A1            9      8      7
1155       A4            6      5      4
1200       A4            3      2      1
```

Desired result for `Student ID`:  0001, 0002, 0003 and `Attribute_ID`: A1.

```
Student_Id Class_ID   Attribute_ID  Value1 Value2 Value3

0001       050        A1            1      2      3
0002       050        A1            1      2      3
0002       155        A1            9      8      7
0003       NULL       NULL          NULL   NULL   NULL
```

Comment: Could you provide sample data?

Comment: @FelixPamittan - added. Hopefully without typos.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved easily using CTE and Partition function (ROW_NUMBER())

```
DECLARE @Student_Class TABLE (Student_ID varchar(10), Class_ID  varchar(10)); 

INSERT INTO @Student_Class VALUES('0001', '0050');
INSERT INTO @Student_Class VALUES('0001', '0150');
INSERT INTO @Student_Class VALUES('0002', '0050');
INSERT INTO @Student_Class VALUES('0002', '0100');
INSERT INTO @Student_Class VALUES('0002', '0155');
INSERT INTO @Student_Class VALUES('0002', '1200');
INSERT INTO @Student_Class VALUES('0002', '1155');
INSERT INTO @Student_Class VALUES('0003', '1155');
INSERT INTO @Student_Class VALUES('0004', '0050');
INSERT INTO @Student_Class VALUES('0004', '0155');

DECLARE @Class TABLE (Class_ID varchar(10), Attribute_ID varchar(10), Value1 int); 

INSERT INTO @Class VALUES('0050',  'A1', 1);
INSERT INTO @Class VALUES('0100',  'A2', 4);
INSERT INTO @Class VALUES('0150',  'A3', 7);
INSERT INTO @Class VALUES('0155',  'A1', 9);
INSERT INTO @Class VALUES('1155',  'A4', 6);
INSERT INTO @Class VALUES('1200',  'A4', 3);

WITH TempData_CTE (Student_ID, Class_ID, Attribute_ID, Value1, rowNum)  
AS
(
    SELECT  sc.Student_ID, 
            c.Class_ID, 
            c.Attribute_ID, 
            c.Value1,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sc.Student_ID ORDER BY sc.Student_ID DESC) AS rowNum
    FROM    @Student_Class sc 
                LEFT JOIN @Class c ON sc.class_id = c.class_id AND c.Attribute_ID = 'A1'
    WHERE   sc.Student_ID IN (0001, 0002, 0003)
)
SELECT  Student_ID, Class_ID, Attribute_ID, Value1 
FROM    TempData_CTE 
WHERE   Class_ID IS NOT NULL OR rowNum = 1
```

Comment: I like your approach, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `left join` should work fine:

```
SELECT sc.student_id, c.*
FROM Student_class sc LEFT JOIN
     Class c
     ON sc.class_id = c.class_id AND c.attribute_id = ...
WHERE sc.student_id IN (...);
```

If there is no match, then you will get only one row for each student and each class that doesn't match.  If a student could have multiple non-matching classes, you can do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sc.student_id, c.*
FROM Student_class sc LEFT JOIN
     Class c
     ON sc.class_id = c.class_id AND c.attribute_id = ...
WHERE sc.student_id IN (...);
```

However, I personally would one one row per non-matching class and I'd include the class in the query:

```
SELECT sc.student_id, sc.class_id, c.*
FROM Student_class sc LEFT JOIN
     Class c
     ON sc.class_id = c.class_id AND c.attribute_id = ...
WHERE sc.student_id IN (...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to run a query which joins the results of two subqueries:

- The list of students with matching classes
- The distinct list of all students

To get the list of all student ids with matching classes, (but not neccesarily all student ids).

```
SELECT
   Student_Class.Student_Id,
   Student_Class.Class_Id 
from
   Student_Class 
   INNER JOIN
      Class 
      ON Student_Class.Class_Id = Class.Class_Id 
WHERE
   Class.Attribute_ID = @Attribute_ID
```

We also need a distinct list of all students. This database almost certainly has a **Student** table, but for the sake of this exercise lets pretend it does not. We'll get the list of student ids through this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Student_Class.Student_ID from Student_Class
```

Now we'll combine these two queries

```
SELECT
   Students.ID,
   Matching_Classes.Class_ID 
FROM
   (
      SELECT DISTINCT
         Student_Class.Student_ID 
      from
         Student_Class 
   )
   Students 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (
         SELECT
            Student_Class.Student_Id,
            Student_Class.Class_Id 
         FROM
            Student_Class 
            INNER JOIN
               Class 
               on Student_Class.Class_Id = Class.Class_Id 
         WHERE
            Class.Attribute_ID = @Attribute_ID
      )
      Matching_Classes 
      ON Students.Student_Id = Matching_Classes.Student_Id
 WHERE Students.ID IN (...)
```